# convert phonegap into steroids

Tags: javascript, cordova, steroids

I'm currently looking into the options of cross platform app development, and since we already have a working (but slow) Phonegap app we consider turning it into a [steroids](/questions/tagged/steroids) app. So I want to know if you can convert it without rewriting all the code. And if the speed of the [steroids](/questions/tagged/steroids) app will be comparable with Titanium or Xamarin, which is our goal.

Comment: Just to be fair, slowness is not 100% phonegap fault, most of the times is the selected UI framework and programming.

Comment: Still it is a problem. and you can't fix it within phonegap

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/) or [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), but I have used [Steroids.js](http://www.appgyver.com/) and have absolutely loved it. From going to a vanilla PhoneGap app with jQuery Mobile to Steroids the change has been very noticeable. The different native UI elements they open up make it feel much less like a web app and more of a true hybrid app.

You wouldn't need to rewrite your code, but if you wanted to take advantage of the different features that make Steroids great then you would need to rewrite some parts. You can use the [PhoneGap to Steroids guide](http://academy.appgyver.com/courses/1/lessons/1) to help you create a Steroids project with your existing code.

Comment: the link you provided is dead "phonegap to steroids guide", can you update it ? I would love to see the guide

Comment: Looks like they took it down and unfortunately I don't use Steroids.js anymore. You can take a look at their [academy](https://academy.appgyver.com/) however and get a feel for the platform.